# A basic level question about grounds in a differential amplifier circuit

Tags: amplifier, differential

As far as I know, voltage is a defined with respect to a common ground in circuits. So if there is a source and a receiver/amplifier; then they should have a common ground if we want to talk meaningfully about the voltages at any node.

Below illustration showing a differential amplifier used for both single-ended and differential inputs:

[image]

I can see in single-ended input case the signal ground of the source is tied to one input of the diff. amplifier. So they share a common ground.

But where is the common ground for the differential input case? Is the source's ground is tied to the ground of the diff. amp? Where is the differential source's ground? Where is the differential amplifier's ground? Can someone draw a more clear example diagram which also shows how and where their grounds are tied?

**Edit:**

I tried to make the confusion more clear with this illustration below:

[image]

We have on the left a differential signalling circuit and it has its own ground GNDA.

We have on the right a differential amplifier and it has its own ground GNDB. Its rails are supplied with +15/-15V wrt GNDB.

Imagine for a moment in time the signal source is outputting +1V and -1V with respect to its own ground GNDA.

One might say here the differential amplifier will take the difference which is +1 - (-1) = 2V and this 2V will be the voltage with respect to GNDB.

Now lets say we measured GNDA = GNDB + 100V.

What does that mean? It doesn't matter or does it?

And here I tried to simulate the situation with LTspice:

[image]

It seems if GNDA - GNDB is greater than some voltages the output corrupts.

What is this about?

Comment: *voltage is a defined with respect to a common ground in circuits* But what if I have **two** such point where I measure the voltage with respect to common ground. But then **I measure between those two points**. Ha! Not using common ground.

Comment: Do you mean something like : I'm feeding two signals comming from sources with separate grounds, what will be the outcome? If that's the case try to add the op-amp supply in your drawing.

Comment: pls see my edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*But where is the common ground for the differential input case?*

It can be anywhere! Assume that the **average** voltage of the two input voltages is at common ground, so 0 Volt. Now what is the differential input voltage ? It is:

\$V_{in,diff} = (V_{inp} - 0) - (V_{inn} - 0) = V_{inp}-V_{inn}\$

Now I use a different common ground which is at + 12.3 V, what do we get now:

\$V_{in,diff} = (V_{inp} - 12.3) - (V_{inn} - 12.3) = V_{inp}-V_{inn}\$

See, no difference!

Since it is the **difference** between \$V_{inp}\$ and \$V_{inp}\$ what counts, whatever the common ground is, it is added and subtracted so the net result is zero.

The common ground is irrelevant. Also they do not need to be tied although in practice they often are. Ethernet (network) cables for example use differential mode signals. The ground does not need to be connected. On both sides of the Ethernet cables small isolation transformers are used to re-define the ground level so that it suits the local circuit.

Also in practice the voltage between inputs and the ground of the circuit will be limited for example by the input voltage range of the amplifier.

Comment: I read your answer thanks. But please see my edit I tried to make my confusion more clear.

Comment: *Now lets say we measured GNDA = GNDB + 100V. What does that mean? It doesn't matter or does it?* As I said, it doesn't matter, do the calculation I show. The **differential** voltage is what is important. Shifting grounds 100 V is irrelevant, it does not change the **difference** that the opamp circuit sees. Have you read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_signaling ?

Comment: I see what matters is the difference but there is also something called "Common Mode Range Extends to Negative Supply" in the data sheet of LM324: https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/LM324-D.PDF Isnt 100V in my case "common mode voltage"?

Comment: See the last sentence in my answer: the input voltage range can **of course** not be exceeded. I was assuming you still did not understand that the ground levels can be different. Of course **obviously** a 100 V ground voltage difference will **fry** an LM324.

Comment: The reason I asked you because I wasnt sure if this https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkiR8.png illustration can really be modelled like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJL7q.png . Because in LTspice thereis a path for current caused by common mode voltage but in reality there is air. I mean if there is no common ground I just dont get where would the 100V common mode voltage's  current return, via which path(current needs a loop)? Thanks for answers

Comment: Well, the first picture with the unconnected GNDA and GNDB is the sort of picture that someone with not so much practical experience would draw. It is **impossible** to make that circuit working for **any** voltage difference between GNDA and GNDB. You're always limited by the input voltage range of the diff. amplifier. Only if you use some means of isolation (like a transformer) it can be OK not to have a connection between GNDA and GNDB. See that picture as a "general idea" and not as an example for a real implementation.

Comment: There does not need to be a loop, just something that prevents excessive voltage differences between GNDA and GNDB. That in turn means that there **MUST** be a connection. The GNDs can only be isolated if the **signal path** is isolated as well. So the picture is **wrong**, either GNDA and GNDB must have a connection **or** there must be isolation in the signal path added.

Comment: Regarding my drawing, GNDA and GNDB are not wired. There is air between GNDA and GNDB. Does that mean there is isolation? Is there a huge impedance between GNDA and GNDB due to air? If there is huge impedance due to air, then the current would be tiny because I = 100V/(air's resistance). Is this way of thinking wrong?

Comment: Yes your thinking is wrong. In a simulator **ALL** voltages must be referenced to one common ground. In your circuit GNDB is not ground, it is simply +100 V. There cannot be a 2nd "floating" circuit. Impedance, air, are all **irrelevant**. Air does not have resistance!!! GNDA and GNDB are either connected or not. When not connected there is no way to limit the (static) voltage difference and this **KILLS** electronics (study "ESD" to learn more). Any resistive path (not air) will eliminate this static voltage difference.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Hard to find such nuances in books.

Comment: please if posśible i need your comment here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/350008/questions-about-single-ended-sources-to-differential-inputs-and-ai-gnd

Answer (score 0):

If you have gndA=gndB+100V it doesn't matter, the differential amplifier will read the difference between the 2 signals so it will have an input voltage of 2V. 
Let me explain it with the simplest differential amplifier:

[image]

Vo = R2/R1 ⋅(V1− V2 ) if r2/r1 = r4/r3, the only important thing is that Vo must be smaller than the positive (or larger than the negative if Vo is negative) rail of the amplifier or it will saturate.